# Convergence of Hilbert functionals on a non-complete domain

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $(H, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathcal{M}\subset H$ some subset with $V:=\mathrm{span}(\mathcal{M})$.

Given a sequence $(x_k)$ in $H$, suppose that the functionals $\varphi_k:=\langle x_k, \cdot\rangle$ converge uniformly on $\mathcal{M}$.

Now if $V$ is *not closed*, can the limit of the operator sequence $(\varphi_k)$ still be uniquely extended to a bounded linear functional $\varphi : H\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, i.e.: is there $x\in H$ such that $\varphi_k\rightarrow \langle x, \cdot\rangle$ uniformly [or at least pointwise] on $\mathcal{M}$?

(If $V$ is closed, the claim should hold by Banach-Steinhaus; yet in the given situation, the missing completeness of $V$ seems problematic.)

Comment: What do you mean by "uniformly" ?

Comment: By "uniformly" I mean that $(\varphi_k)$ is uniformly Cauchy on $\mathcal{M}$, that is: 

$\forall\varepsilon>0$ there is $N>0$  such that $\sup_{v\in\mathcal{M}}|\varphi_n(v) - \varphi_m(v)| \leq \varepsilon$ for each $m,n\geq N$.

Later on, when writing "$\varphi_k \rightarrow \langle x,\cdot\rangle$ uniformly" I mean uniform convergence (of functions) on $\mathcal{M}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be an orthonormal basis in $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{M}=\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty.$ Consider $x_k=\sum_{n=1}^kn^{-1/2}e_n.$ Then for $l>k$ we get
$$ |\varphi_l(e_n)-\varphi_k(e_n)|=|\langle e_n,x_l\rangle -\langle e_n,x_k\rangle|
\\
=\begin{cases}n^{-1/2} & k< n\le l\\
0 & {\rm otherwise}
\end{cases}\quad <k^{-1/2}$$
Thus $\varphi_k$ satisfy the uniform Cauchy condition on $\mathcal{M}.$
However the sequence $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is unbounded. Therefore such $x$ does not exist.